# How can pytest enable print() in src code?

Tags: python, printing, pytest

Here's my code

in module.py:

```
def myFunc():
    print('aaa')
```

in test_module.py:

```
def test_myFunc():
    print('bbb')
    myFunc()
```

If I run `pytest -s test_module.py` then I can see printout `bbb`; but I can't see printout `aaa`.
Actually I also tried to `import logging` to play with logger, also no luck.

So basically my question is, when triggering `pytest`, how can we see printout from the src code?

Comment: Pytest intercepts prints and logging. They will be shown on a failure only. This way the application will not mess up pytest's output. There are command line arguments to change the behaviour.

Comment: Actually `pytest -s` should have done it, as it disables capturing the output - I suspect that there is something else going on in the environment (a configuration, a plugin, ...).

Comment: Without further information this cannot be answered, as with the given example it would just work.

Comment: I can't reproduce, are you using `capsys` / `capfd` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can confirm that `pytest -s` does the job.

```sh
pytest -s test_module.py

# test_module.py bbb
# aaa
```

However it may be a better idea to use Python `logging` module for debugging purpose. You just need to import `logging` and to replace the print by appropriate level call to `logging.info()` for example.

```
# module.py
import logging

def myFunc():
    logging.info('aaa')

# test_module.py
from module import myFunc
import logging

def test_myFunc():
    logging.info('bbb')
    myFunc()
```

And here is the output.

```sh
pytest --log-cli-level=INFO test_module.py 

# INFO     root:test_module.py:6 bbb
# INFO     root:module.py:4 aaa
```

More information in the [Pytest doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/logging.html) dedicated to logging.

Comment: Yeah thanks! I've already realized logging is much better way than print(), and designed for this.